# Create a transparent window in a div background with css and javascript

Tags: javascript, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to implement an effect in a webpage. The webpage must be fully covered with a background with a transparent window (this window will basically highlight some page of the page to draw user's attention).
The size of the window is unknown beforehand and the effect must be implemented in the frontend. So I'm free to use html, css and js.

[image: visualisation]

I don't know a way this effect can be achieved with css only. And I cannot use something like a png image background, because the size and the dimensions of the transparent window will change dynamically. I'm thinking of generating canvas for and use it as a background image for the div element.

Is this possible to generate a canvas as per my example image and use it as a background?
Can you, please, provide an example?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you show what you've attempted so far?

Comment: Please follow the site guidelines, which clearly requires asker to show their attempts in the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a giant `box-shadow`:

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3999/Tilt-Shift_-_Cityscene.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.window {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border: 5px solid red;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 99999px rgba(0, 255, 0, .25)
}
```

```html
<div class="window"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Another approach would be via the [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) CSS property, where the clip path is used to define the visible region of the green "overlay".

Using the [Clippy](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) tool, you can modify the "frame" clip-path (from the tools preset library) to suit your needs. Here's an example of how the technique can be used to achieve what you require, and what each coordinate of the clip-path corresponds to:

```css
.overlay {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(0,255,0,0.5);

  /* Defines the portion of the green overlay to be drawn and clipped */
  clip-path: polygon(
    0% 0%, 
    0% 100%, 
    25% 100%, /* Bottom left sideline of clipped rectangle */
    25% 25%, /* Top left corner of clipped rectangle */
    75% 25%, /* Top right corner of clipped rectangle */
    75% 75%, /* Bottom right corner of clipped rectangle */
    25% 75%,  /* Bottom left corner of clipped rectangle */
    25% 100%, /* Bottom left baseline of clipped rectangle */
    100% 100%,
    100% 0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay"></div>
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505811210036-052144988918?w=1080" />
```

You could then generalize a solution for a visible rectangular region based on a `clip-path` with JavaScript like this:

```js
/* Calculates clip paths with rectangular "cutout" for specified element  */
const setClipPath = (element, { left, top, width, height }) => {
 
  element.style.clipPath = `polygon(
    0% 0%, 
    0% 100%, 
    ${left}% 100%,
    ${left}% ${top}%,
    ${left + width}% ${top}%,
    ${left + width}% ${top + height}%,
    ${left}% ${top + height}%,
    ${left}% 100%,
    100% 100%,
    100% 0%)
  `;
}

setClipPath(document.querySelector(".overlay"), {
  top : 10, 
  left : 10, 
  width : 30, 
  height : 30
});
```

```css
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay"></div>
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1505811210036-052144988918?w=1080" />
```

Comment: Even though I went with the box-shadow answer. Thanks for adding the `clip-path` solution.

Answer (score 2):

Another idea using border

Reponsive

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3999/Tilt-Shift_-_Cityscene.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.window {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:20vh 30vw;
  border-color:rgba(0, 255, 0, .25);
}
```

```html
<div class="window"></div>
```

Or with fixed sizes

```css
body {
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3999/Tilt-Shift_-_Cityscene.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.window {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  border-style:solid;
  border-width:calc(50vh - 80px) calc(50vw - 100px);
  border-color:rgba(0, 255, 0, .25);
}
```

```html
<div class="window"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a single div that fills the entire screen. The transparent window is the the inside of the div, and the transparent background is the border. Using CSS, use the `border-width` properties to control the window's position, and use the `height` and `width` properties to set the window's size.

```css
#overlay {
  /* full page overlay */
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  z-index: 2;
  
  /* window size */
  width: 150px;
  height: 20px;
  
  /* window position */
  border-top: 50px;
  border-left: 50px;
  border-bottom: 10000px;
  border-right: 10000px;
  
  /* window colour */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  
  /* frame colour */
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgba(50,150,250,0.5);

}

p {
  margin: 50px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p>A paragraph of text</p>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```